# Random image with htaccess only

Tags: image, .htaccess, random

I'm working on a small web portal project and I want to customize one splash screen image but I'm not allowed to change the code of the web portal.

So the code is linked to image.jpg

Does it is possible to have a random image with .htaccess?

Something like that:

When the webportal is calling for image.jpg redirect randomly to image1.jpg, image2.jpg ... until image5.jpg

Kind regards,
steph!

Answer (score 0):

What about linking the src of the image to a php script instead ? (if you are working with php)

like ,

```
<img src="path/myimage.php" />
```

select a random image file , set the right headers with header() , use file_get_content(imagepath) ,  and output the string with die($myimagestring) in a php file if you use php.

i dont think you could do that only with an htaccess.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I can't change the code. Moreover php is not supported by the server.